# carousel exception

Tags: jquery, asp.net

**Following is my page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dish.TestForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Register TagName="AdPanelDefault" TagPrefix="dish" Src="~/abc.ascx" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
                wrap: 'circular'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrap">
        <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
            <li>
                <img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"
                    alt="" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to implement **carousel** I am getting following exception .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some issue in the footer control while adding the Javascript file reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are loading jQuery and jCarousel files correctly. =), and path of the files are correct.